# Returning object using HTTP GET request is undefined

Tags: javascript, http, youtube, youtube-api

I'm making a GET request in order to get video data object of YouTube through link. I think I don't understand here is when I `console.log` the returned request it is getting logged to the browser console

```js
function videoThumb(url){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      //printing to the console
      console.log(myArr);
      //object returned per call
      return myArr;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
  
var obj = videoThumb("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=QIc00XImJmA&key=AIzaSyCC0R6ZmeHW0pXVQxE7RJPTt5_JvwTGwXA")

//obj should have returned value from `videoThumb`
```

But when I store the returned object value in variable `obj`, then calling `obj` again returning `undefined`.

Comment: function videoThumb(url) isn't returning a value hence its undefined. if you want to get hold of xmlHttp object add a return statement at the bottom of the function .

Comment: What do you mean at the bottom of the function? If I take it out of event callback value gets empty. Because it should return after event is fired

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable out of `xmlhttp` scope.

```js
function videoThumb(url){
     var r = false,
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             // update the variable response
             r = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false); // change async to false to wait for response although this is bad!
     xmlhttp.send();
     return r;
}

var obj = videoThumb("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=QIc00XImJmA&key=AIzaSyCC0R6ZmeHW0pXVQxE7RJPTt5_JvwTGwXA");
//obj should have returned value from `videoThumb` 
console.log(obj);
```

The above solution is sort of bad for timing and webpage performance. I got the following error using this, and think it's because I called the function at page load.

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The best way which I recommend is using a callback function like below.

```js
    function videoThumb(url, callback){
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 // update the variable response
                 callback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
    }

videoThumb("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=QIc00XImJmA&key=AIzaSyCC0R6ZmeHW0pXVQxE7RJPTt5_JvwTGwXA", function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: See you should not `console.log` in callback function but store the response  in variable that returned obejct would be useful for further development. When you change console.log to return value of variable equaling `videoThumb` is undefined

Comment: Examples are not meant to be production ready code, its just a guideline to ingest the idea of approach. i would recommend reading around async events and how to handle them with callbacks or promises .